# Execute a remote command after sudo - su anotheruser in Rundeck

Tags: ssh, sudo, solaris

I'm new with Rundeck and completely amazed with it and I'm trying to execute a job and my scenario is detailed below:

- Rundeck is configured with ssh passwordless authentication for user master between node Server (rundeck server) and node Target (remote Solaris host) for user "master"
- In node Target I want to execute a script `/app/acme/stopApp.sh` with a user `appmanager`
- Normally and manually, when I need to run script above I proceed with

  ```
  ssh master@server 
  sudo su - appmanager
  ```

  or simply

  ```
  ssh -t master@server 'sudo su - appmanager'
  ```

  works without password and finally run (as appmanager)

  ```
  /app/acme/stopApp.sh
  ```

But I'm not sure how can I reproduce these steps using Rundeck. I read in some previous messages that for each job line rundeck use a new ssh connection, so the workflow below always fails for me with the messages:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Remote command failed with exit status 1
```

Please someone could help me with some information to solve this issue.

Without this functionality I wouldn't be able to introduce a little DevOps in my department.

I read the user guide and admin guide but I couldn't find an easy example, neither in this forum, to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know anything about rundeck, take my advice with a large grain of salt, but if you are getting a `no tty present` message from sudo, most probably, sudo'ing into this account from which ever account you are coming from, is not allowed with a NOPASSWORD directive in the sudoers file and it is expecting you to enter a password. And since you are establishing a headless connection (i.e. notty), it is failing after finding no place to read this password from.

Scan your sudoers file and see if you can find a relevant line regarding this sudo/login combination and play with it.

On a less likely scenario, rundeck might have its override of sudo in some way but I don't count on it too much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that /etc/sudoers has "requiretty" ... which means you need a tty to run the sudo command. One fix is to remove this requirement for the specific user by adding this to /etc/sudoers on the machine(s):

`Defaults:someuser !requiretty`